# What kind of tree was this?

Tags: trees

[image]     I found this log in the woods any idea what it is?

Comment: What sorts of living trees was it near to? Any likely suspects among those? ....Did you shine it up after you found it? It sure is pretty. Finally, ..... if no one knows on this site, maybe try the woodworking group?:  ...   https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/